# What are good techniques to handle state and state change in game development?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, language-agnostic, state-machine

I'm an experienced developer new to game development, and I have made a reasonably simple but working 3D platformer game and am looking for ways to make the architecture more scalable.

**What is a good way to handle state in game development?**
A very naive approach is to have multiple booleans like:

```
time_stopped = True
time_slow_motion = False
level_loaded = True
level_paused = True
level_completed = False
```

This is very inflexible since a developer error could lead to `time_stopped = True` and `time_slow_motion = True` at the same time, which would destroy game logic.

I'm looking for a better approach in the direction of:

```
class TimeState:
    STOPPED = 0
    SLOW_MOTION = 1
    NORMAL = 2
    current_state = 0

    def isStopped(self):
        if current_state == self.STOPPED: return True
```

But how would I handle multiple groups of state in a good way? I could create a `LevelState` which had `LOADED`, `PAUSED` and `COMPLETED` states. But how do I handle overlapping groups like when `LevelState` and `TimeState` `PAUSED` should always be the same?
Is there a good design pattern or a good practice on how to solve state management?

**What is a good way to handle state change?**
My thoughts are to either give the state object eg. `LevelState` callback functions to execute on any given state change - or to poll the state object each game loop like `if level_state.changedTo() == LevelState.COMPLETED: doStuff()`. Are there better ways to handle this? Message queues/events? I don't want to embed logic into the state objects.
I'm also interested in if one should handle both `changedFrom` and `changedTo` events, and what would happen if logic triggered by `changedFrom` changes the state of the object before the `changedTo` logic is triggered - who wins?

I don't want implementation/language specific answers but tips on a good way to think architecturally wise.

Comment: use python set() and make sets, you can base your logic on set.issubset(), etc ... also, i believe you want to utilize observer pattern

Comment: @pyInTheSky Thanks for pointing out observer pattern! I'm aware of efficient ways to code this in python (though the current game is in C#), but tried to make examples more readable than fast

Comment: if you just want an easy state machine, i posted this on active state: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577693-dynamically-generated-python-state-machine/  :: i have modified it but not reposted, you can easily switch it to return a tuple and have a run() function that acts as an arbiter, so it doesn't build up a giant call stack.  There are also some other mods i haven't uploaded, like asking the sm to regenerate itself if you add a state, etc... but it is very simple and maybe can help you

Comment: State machines are typically the way to handle this sort of thing, though something like pausing the game is probably easier with just a simple boolean.

Answer (score 3):

This is such a common thing that there is even a pattern: [The State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)

At the start, it seems like this approach has some overhead, but as the logic gets more complicated you will see the benefits.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the State Pattern. Of course I found it through google but I'm wondering if there are variations/expansions of it that match game development better (since it's very general/simple). I'm also interested in how I can handle the change of state and overlapping state groups.